# How to add git prehook to tslint?

Tags: node.js, git, tslint

i am trying to add prehook if there is any linting issue with the code fail to commit.what is correct approach to implement it.

tslint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
sh ./npm-install.sh
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "npm-install error, exiting.."
  exit 1
fi
echo "Running ts lint"
npm run lint
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Unit tests error, exiting.."
  exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 10):

I had a successful experience to implement this with:

1. `husky` => to specify git hook
2. `lint-staged` => run a command to staged files in git (so no need to run tslint to all files)

Reference:

1. https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/husky

in `package.json`, specify `lint-staged` and `pre-commit` in `husky` field:

```
"dependencies": ...,
"devDependencies": ...,
"scripts" ...,
"husky": {
    "hooks": {
        "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
},
"lint-staged": {
    "*.ts": [ // target to all typescript files in staged stage in git
      "npm run lint", // your lint command
      "git add"   
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pre-commit

> pre-commit is a pre-commit hook installer for git. It will ensure that your npm test (or other specified scripts) passes before you can commit your changes. This all conveniently configured in your package.json.

Answer (score 2):

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "app name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": "author",
  "contributors": [

  ],
  "description": "...",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "precommit": "lint-staged"
  },
  ...,
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{ts,js,sccs,json}": [
      "ng lint app-name --fix",
      "./node_modules/.bin/prettier --write",
      "git add"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "lint-staged": "^7.2.0",
    "prettier": "^1.13.5",
    "ts-node": "^6.1.2",
    "tslint": "^5.10.0",
    "typescript": "2.7.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: you do not need to add ```app-name``` as linter option and it is general a better practice to declare it as script and then call that. and wtf is ```sccs```??